# Мобильное приложение к существующему сайту

Tags: php, android, api, rest

Есть сайт, который был заказан у разработчика. Написан на PHP (MVC) + SQL. По сути простой поиск туров в БД сайта. Есть адаптивный дизайн для мобильных, но теперь требуется приложение для андроид.

Вопрос: кто должен (как обычно в практике) выполнить серверную часть (API) для приложения на андроид? Разработчик приложения самостоятельно, изучив структуру БД и написав под себя API или разработчик сайта, но предварительно получив требования (какие запросы и ответы выдает сервер) от разработчика приложения?

Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно организовать данную работу?

Answer (score 4):

В идеальном мире это происходит так: Изначально API так сделано, что ничего допиливать не надо и мобильному разработчику просто выдают документацию (так же изначально сделанную) к API, дизайн и ТЗ.

В реальном мире никакого "правильного" способа нет. Если разработчик сайта имеет нужный опыт - напишет/допишет нужное API. Если опыта нет - возможно сможет сделать всё же лучше, чем мобильный разработчик. А может и нет. Мобильный разработчик тоже не факт что сможет сходу выдать какое API ему нужно. ИМХО оба разработчика должны работать в паре и договариваться на ходу. Ну или приглашается ещё и аналитик, который им ТЗ напишет, по которому API и приложение будет делаться.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Мой комментарий несовсем отвечает на ваш вопрос, но возможно будет полезен, если вы не знали о такой технологии.
Если у вас есть адаптивная верстка под мобилу, то быть может вам подойдет технология создания приложений на андроид TWA (по сути - это веб приложение, которое выглядит и ведет себя как нативное).
Вот тут есть подробности https://habr.com/ru/post/439238/